# Signing Data with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have some data that needs to be signed a the client side, using a private key.

The signature will then be sent to the server side for verification (using a known public key). Is there any good implementation of javascript open ssl private key signature mechanism?

Comment: [WebCrypto](http://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/)?

Answer (score 1):

I found [Stanford Javascript Cryptography Library](https://crypto.stanford.edu/sjcl/). It supports ECDSA, for my use case, the more common RSA, Hash functions etc.

The only problem with ECDSA is it does not interpret compressed EC public keys (33 bytes) correctly. (It is easy to work around this problem)

Comment: It will probably only work on the client. Servers (like Node.js), don't have the Navigator object. (Servers are usually the ones that sign, while clients are usually the ones that verify).